# React Native dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, native-base

I want to start programming in `React-native` and have few problems:

-Whenever I run

```
 npm install -g react-native
```

get this:

```
PS C:\Users\Name> npm install -g react-native
C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\react-native -> 
C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\local- 
cli\wrong-react-native.js
npm WARN react-native@0.57.3 requires a peer of react@16.6.0-alpha.8af6728 
but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-check-constants@7.0.0-beta.38 requires a peer of 
@babel/core@7.0.0-beta.38 but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 
(node_modules\react-native\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ react-native@0.57.3
added 39 packages from 55 contributors, removed 20 packages and updated 82 
packages in 32.884s
```

However, if I manually install these packages, they still don't register as installed and I am getting the same error messages.

-The second problem I come across is, with expo (I think).
I have followed the instructions of the `react native` manual on facebook's `github`, but whenever I try to install `native-base` package, always get the message `unable to resolve module native-base`.

I tried to follow the steps that should lead me to solving the problem of clearing watchman and deleting node_modules but nothing helped. 
I also couldn't implement `react-native-swiper` because of the same problem.

Whenever I install them, get the dependencies Warnings but when I install the dependencies the warnings don't go away.

It seems that the packages don't get installed if I issue the command. I thought that could be the problem but haven't been able to find a resolution to that.

Comment: Those are two separate questions...

Comment: oh, i'm sorry, should i have posted two separate questions? @KamilNaja I just thought that they might be connected because the package dependencies don't vanish even if i install them so i thought that might have been the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-native` should not be installed as global. It should be installed in your project directory.

I think that instead of `react-native` you meant to install `react-native-cli`
which gives you cli options for building React-Native apps such as `react-native init` to start a project etc.

By using the `react-native-cli` module, using the `native-base` module becomes much easier as after doing `npm i -S native-base` you have to just run `react-native link` as written in the documentation.

Comment: where would i have to install native-base? should i install it in the project folder or global? @Ashniu123

Comment: @Niyu it would be in the project folder

Comment: i'm sorry if it's a bit too much to ask, but could you tell me which commands i have to run in which folder, i'm a little bit confused right now. @Ashniu123

Comment: For installing react-native-cli
On your terminal (or cmd or powershell) 

> npm install --global react-native-cli

> cd /YourWorkspace

/YourWorkspace > react-native init first-app

/YourWorkspace > cd first-app

Here you can do `react-native run-android` to run the app!

To install native-base 

/YourWorkspace/first-app > npm install --save native-base

/YourWorkspace/first-app > react-native link

Now use components from native-base!

Comment: Hope you understand... it is a bit messy as comments don't get formatted like answers do

Answer (score 0):

Try delete your node_modules folder and re-install

npm i

You can also try clean npm cache.

Edit - better way will be install create-react-native-app, that should works outside the box.
https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it with this command `npm install -g react-native-cli` or with the sudo `sudo npm install -g react-native-cli`. Make sure you have installed the npm and node in your device